# How should I use backup/restore vs import-ldif/export-ldif

Tags: ldap

I'm looking to take periodic backups of an ldap server for disaster recovery. It seems that data can be backed up and recovered via both backup/restore and export-ldif/import-ldif.

What are the advantages of each system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the server software, `backup` and `restore` are probably faster, since presumably the operate on the binary copy of the database. The LDIF would be useful when a totally new environment needs to be created. LDAP server administrators should use both methods. If the server runs on Solaris, then a ZFS snapshot should also be created.